# First 1000 bytes of a variable

Tags: perl, text, binary-data, unpack

Is this usage of `unpack` correct if I would like to try this guessing subroutine with the variables first 1000 bytes?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.10.1;

my $var = ...;
my $part = unpack( 'b1000', $var ) ;

sub is_binary_data {
    local $_ = shift;
    (   tr/ -~//c / length  ) >= .3;
}

if ( is_binary_data( $part ) ) {
    say "Binary";
}
else {
    say "Text";
}
```

Comment: Another option for checking for binary data might be using `Encode::Guess` (http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode/Guess.html) which is used to determine a string's character encoding.  Set your known character encoding as the only option for it to try; if it fails, you know you have binary data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it isn't since unpack will create a string of 0 and 1's (up to 1000 of them) which would certainly pass the ascii test (which I believe `tr, -~,,c / length` is)

I would suggest using just `substr ($var, 0, 1000)` instead.

Also, maybe `\r` and `\n` should appear in the `tr//`.

Comment: Beware of course that technically this extracts the first 1000 characters; which may make a difference if `$var` is a Unicode string

Comment: I would suggest the `tr//` be expanded to `\x09-\x0d -~`. `\x09-\x0d` is equivelent to POSIX `[:space:]` and ` -~` is equivelent to POSIX `[:print:]`. This should cover what most people would consider ASCII text. It would be nice if `tr//` could use character classes, or `s/[^[:print:][:space:]]//g;` wasn't about 15 time slower.

Comment: @LeoNerd, Depends what you mean by "Unicode string". If you mean a string stored using the UTF8=1 format, `substr($_,0,1000)` works fine. If you mean a string that contains characters above 255, then the question makes no sense. (One can't find the first 1000 bytes of something that isn't bytes.)